# calling AngularJS controller outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m trying to convert an AngularJS form to ExtJs form. I m totally newbie in AngularJS and ExtJS. Finally i could handle the view part in the ExtJS  but i guess i need to use the controller from AngularJS. Is there any way to use the data which i get from ExtJS with AngularJS controller ? 
For example, the method which would do the job in the controller method is: "createAppInProject"

How could i call this method from outside of the controller ?

```
 angular.module('sincapp.controllers')
                .controller('AppsCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$state', '$compile', '$timeout', '$log', '$window', 'UserService', 'AppStoreService', 'Globals', 'growl', 'AppService', 'DockingWindowsService',
                    function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $state, $compile, $timeout, $log, $window, UserService, AppStoreService, Globals, Notifier, AppService, DockingWindowsService) {

            $scope.createAppInProject = function (name, description, version, tags, language, license, price, longdescription, note) {
                                var creator = UserService.userName;
                                AppService.createAppInProject(name, description, version, creator, tags, language, license, price, longdescription, note, $scope.selectedProject);
                            };
         }]);
```

this didnt help me :

```
$('#AppsCtrl').scope().createAppInProject("as","ss","sa","sas","ddasdsa","asdasd","sasd","dds","asd");
```

Comment: Have you actually initialized an angular controller on your page on an element with an id of `AppsCtrl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you question is about the architecture for a mix application, for this case you could look the [best practices of the angular JS community](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), to find guidelines and some examples.

In my opinion you could use the `HTMLElement.dataset` attributes to define your custom data to share from ExtJs. it's possible to find [the reference and example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Angular access to this attributes with [Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), look for the tittle **Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM** there is an example to watch the attributes of an `HTMLElement`. A clock.

When you have the data in the directive you can use **ControllerAs** see the [angular styleguide, section directive and controllerAs](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#directives-and-controlleras) to share the data with other controllers or services inside angular.

Also is the data is to large, i suggest you could use localstorage, [here are some good libraries](http://bower.io/search/?q=localstorage).

Comment: @tolquito also, you could try this library [Adapter for angular and Sencha Touch](https://github.com/tbosch/sencha-touch-angular-adapter), Tobias is from the AngularJs Core Team

Answer (score 0):

You should use `angular.element()` instead of just jQuery.

```
angular.element($('#AppsCtrl')).scope().createAppInProject("as","ss","sa","sas","ddasdsa","asdasd","sasd","dds","asd");`
```

Comment: angular.element($('#AppsCtrl')).scope() is unidentified.. Although angular.element($('#AppsCtrl')) is defined.

Comment: Is `$('#AppsCtrl')` not null?